# Why do I get an AttributeError on str.sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x, traceback

This is my code:

```
bands = []
band = []
headline = input('Headline: ')
while band != "":
  bands.append(band)
  band = input('Band: ')
band.sort()
print(headline)
for band in bands:
  print(band)
```

its for the user to input a list of names and for it to sort it alphabetically but i keep getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 7, in <module>
    band.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

could someone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to sort `band` which is a string and thus immutable in Python. This is probably a typo and you wanted to to `bands.sort()`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 7, in <module>
    bands.sort()
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'list'

Comment: sorry I was just retarded and changed my code before adding in your answer and forgot that so sorry again you were right.XD